# conversion from 'double' to 'int' in VS2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, int, double, type-conversion

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for the first time in my life for a school assignment.... so far it's pretty simple, yet I'm running into trouble trying to convert a 'double' to an 'int'. I understand that both `trunc()` and `round()` do not work in VS2010, however i'm not sure how else I can do this.... here's my code:

```
double q = double floor((p+r)/2);
q = (int) q;
mergeSort(v,p,q);

mergeSort(v,q+1,r);

merge(v,p,q,r);
```

i need to make the variable `q` an int in order to work with the rest of my code... however casting does not seem to be working as I am getting these errors:

`warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data`

I know these are only warnings but my code still fails... is there any other way around this?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile at all, what's that `double` to the _right_ of the `=` doing there?

Comment: Why are you using floating point at all for this calculation? Working with `int`s would be just fine.

Comment: if I leave it off I get the following error `error C2668: 'floor' : ambiguous call to overloaded function` .... `could be 'long double floor(long double) or       'float floor(float)' or       'double floor(double)`

Comment: In that case you didn't copy/paste your code correctly. The code in the question will give another error. A proper error, not a _warning_ like in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are converting a double to an int, you wil always have a loss of data, which is what the warning is about. Since you know that this is indeed the desired result, you can ignore the warning.
However, you should use a

```
static_cast<int>(q)
```

instead of just `(int)q;`